# Can I change my android application style at runtime?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change the manifest style when the user chooses a setting in the preferences file or settings. I have a setting in my apk which includes a list of preferences with three entries `{Style_1, Style_2, Style_3}`. I want to change the style color, like `primaryColor`, when the user clicks a style. How can I do this?

Comment: yes, you can apply the theme in oncreate method programmatically but you need to recreate the activity to which you apply new theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, setting theme after a button click or option choosen could be harsh for an **Activity** to handle.
What I am suggesting you is to reload your activity on button click but before that simply save the ***style_name*** , the user want to apply in internal memory or **Shared** **Preferences**. You can apply *shared* *preference* simply looking at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

At the start of **onCreate** of your activity, apply that fetching part of *shared* *preferences* and apply the theme as user has indicated. This would help you to preserve the theme for that user until s/he uninstall that application or clears the app data.
If s/he is using the application for first time, the stored ***style_name*** string would be null so load your application with default theme.

You can simply reload your activity on button click by using the below code:

```
public void onClick (View v){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this easily, I do it all the time.

Just call this method before setContentView like this:

```
 setTheme(R.style.Theme);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```

Now what I do is that i take a static int variable in the app constants and change it according to my theme. Then i do something like this

```
 //This is in my constants file
 public static int CURRENT_THEME = R.style.AppTheme;

 //This is in my onCreate of every Activity.
 setTheme(Constants.CURRENT_THEME);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set Theme like this:

```
    activity.setTheme(R.style.theme_large);
    activity.setTheme(R.style.theme_small);

    <style name="theme_large">
            <item name="main_background">@drawable/background_red</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="button_light">@color/button_light</item>
    </style>



    <style name="theme_small">
            <item name="main_background">@drawable/background_red</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="button_light">@color/button_light</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create Two Style

```
 setTheme(darkTheme ? R.style.AppThemeDark : R.style.AppThemeLight);

<style name="AppThemeDark">
            <item name="main_background">@drawable/background_dark</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="button_light">@color/button_dark</item>
    </style>



<style name="AppThemeLight">
        <item name="main_background">@drawable/background_light</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
        <item name="button_light">@color/button_light</item>
</style>
```